# Precomputing Function with ReplaceAll[]

Tags: functions, function-construction, timing

I have a function `f` that is a combination of multiple other functions `g_i`, which themselves are combinations of other functions `h_ij`

```
f=Function[{x},g_1[x]+g_2[x]+...+g_n[x]]
g_i=Function[{x},h_i1[x]+h_i2[x]+...+h_im[x]]
```

If I evaluate `f[0]` the evaluation takes about 20 seconds, however if I define `F=f[x]` then run `F/.{x->0}` the evaluation takes about 0.01 seconds.

Is it possible to "precompute" `f` so I don't need to use `ReplaceAll` to benefit from the speed boost?

**Example Code**

```
g = Table[With[{b = i},
  Function[{x}, Values[Solve[a*b^x == I, a][[1, 1]] ] ] ],
  {i, Table[RandomComplex[], 1000]} 
];

f = Function[{x}, Total[Through[g[x] ] ] ];
```

When running `f[4]` I get an evaluation time of ~0.08 seconds, but when running `F=f[x]; F/.{x->4}` the run time is ~0.004 seconds.

Comment: Could you update your code so the other can replicate the issue.

Comment: The actual code is about 1000 lines long, is there another way to give more info?

Comment: Can you provide a relatively simple example that illustrates the issue?

Comment: Maybe, you are looking for `f=Function[{x},Evaluate[g_1[x]+g_2[x]+...+g_n[x]]]`?

Comment: What you do is essentially solve the set of equations every time. As @HenrikSchumacher suggested, use `Evaluate`.

Comment: `Evaluate` did the trick. I tried it previously but had used it incorrectly. Thanks All.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Evaluate` around the functions in `f` did the trick, as suggested in the comments.

```
 f=Function[{x},Evaluate[g_1[x]+g_2[x]+...+g_n[x]]]
```